# Update a field based on the content of a field in another table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, sql-update

These table descriptions are vague to protect the data I am working with. I apologize in advance but i must keep the details limited. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I have 2 tables that look like this:

**Table 1**:

```
Facility, Person, ID, Group
```

**Table 2**:

```
ID, Type, Date
```

I want to update the `Group` in Table 1 based on the `Type` in Table 2, but only where it matches a certain `Facility`.

I tried this:

```
UPDATE Table 1
SET Group = 'Big'
FROM Table 1 T1 
INNER JOIN Table 2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE Type = 'B' AND Facility LIKE '%Game%'`
```

But the result is an update to all the fields with `Facility` like '%Game%'.

A `SELECT` statement returns all the correct results. I am unsure what is wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you show an example of the data, please?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  You just want to use the alias in the `update` rather than the table name:

```
UPDATE T1
    SET Group = 'Big'
    from Table 1 T1 INNER JOIN
         Table 2 T2
         on T1.ID = T2.ID
    WHERE Type = 'B' AND Facility like '%Game%'
```

Comment: This solution still updates all records regardless on the Type field.